# random uniform dot in triangle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles, random

$\triangle ABC$ has sides of length $45,60$ and $75$. Place a point $D$ randomly and uniformly inside the triangle. What is the expected value of the sum of perpendicular distances from point $D$ to the triangle's three sides?

Geometrically it should be $47$ but I cannot rigorously prove it. Any help please?

Comment: Are you allowed to use integrals?

Comment: sure, any soft like wolfram and maple is fine.

Comment: this problem perfectly fits to [trilinear coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_coordinates) system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use $AB=60$ along the $x$ axis, $AC=45$ along the $y$ axis. $A=(0,0)$, $B=(60,0)$, $C=(0,45)$. $BC=75$, and we will need to first calculate the equation of the line.
$$\begin{align}y&=ax+b\\0&=60a+b\\45&=0a+b\end{align}$$
This yield $b=45$ and $a=-\frac34$. The distance from a point$(x,y)$ inside the triangle to the $AB$ side is $y$, to the $AC$ side is $x$, and to the $BC$ side is [(from wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_two_points)$$d(x,y)=\frac{|45x+60y-45\cdot 60|}{75}=36-\frac35x-\frac45y$$
The sum of the distances will be $$S=x+y+d(x,y)=36+\frac25x+\frac15y$$. With uniform distribution, $$\begin{align}\bar S&=\frac{\iint_\triangle S dxdy}{\iint_\triangle dxdy}\\&=\frac{\int_0^{60}dx\int_0^{45-\frac34x}dy (36+\frac25 x+\frac 15 y)}{\int_0^{60}dx\int_0^{45-\frac34x}dy}\end{align}$$